# Angular: "AppRoutingModule" gets ignored and routes don't work

Tags: angular, routes

It's a simple issue, I guess, but I can't figure out where does it come from. My router simply doesnt't work!

The NavBar:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">
<a routerLink="admin" routerLinkActive="active">Admin</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Home</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
```

The app.module:

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';



  @NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent, NavbarComponent, HomeComponent, AdminComponent],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        RouterModule,
      ], etc
```

App.routingModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './components/admin/admin.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '**',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

No mather what I type in the "a", the admin page wont appear. One hint I got from stackBlitz is that he doesnt consider my AppRoutingModule a module...Can someone help me out?

Comment: @melville which's the filename of app routing module ?

Comment: @Jesus, the name of the file is app-routing.module.ts

Comment: Try changing the order so that the `admin` path is after the `**` path.

Comment: so I just leave it empty?

Comment: It worked, i guesse, changing the order and leaving the export empty...so i don't know, if you guys want to have an answer so I can give points...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change your imports/exports, instead you can change your `routes`. The order of routes is critical, from the documentation:

> The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by
>   design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching
>   routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific
>   routes. In the configuration above, routes with a static path are
>   listed first, followed by an empty path route, that matches the
>   default route. The wildcard route comes last because it matches every
>   URL and should be selected only if no other routes are matched first.

Try the following putting the "catch-all" route at the end of the array and adding a "default"/`''` route to go to `HomeComponent`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './components/admin/admin.component';

const routes: Routes = [  
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: it helped, really, and one more thing to keep in mind :) Thank you very much @Alexander